# How to prevent `gulp-uglify` from moving my global variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) with my gulp setup to mimify my js code for production environment.

I have code like this

```
var test = 1;

function getTest(myTest)
{
   if(!myTest) {
      return test;
   }

  return myTest;
}
```

However when I run gulp the output becomes (I kept it clean for readability)

```
function getTest(myTest)
{
   if(!myTest) {
      return test;
   }

  return myTest;
}
var test = 1;
```

How can I prevent `gulp-uglify` from changing the order or my global variables.

I first concatenate my files, then uglify.

I try to pass the following object to `uglify` but it is still shifting the order.

```
uglify({ mangle: false })
uglify({ mangle: { reserved: ['test'] } })
```

Here is a list of the dependencies

```
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ignore": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7"
  }
```

here is my gulp task

```
gulp.task('compileJs', function () {
        gulp.src(jsFiles['final'])
               .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
               //only uglify if gulp is ran with '--type production'
               .pipe(isProduction() ? uglify() : gutil.noop())
               .pipe(concat('final.js'))
               .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./Public/Js'));

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `hoist_funs` option to `false`.

```
.pipe(uglify({
    compress: {
        hoist_funs: false
    }
})
```

Comment: That is giving me the following error `events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript`  this is what I called ` uglify({ hoist_funs: false })`

Comment: @MikeA added the correct syntax in case that is were your problem lies. The `hoist_funs` belongs to the `compress` option.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it!